# When listing Uniswap V3 tokens for the first time, how do set the Min/Max price?

Tags: ico, uniswapv3

When listing Uniswap V3 tokens for the first time, I'm confused about what the "Set Price Range (Min/Max)" is about.

I am trying to create the first liquidity pool(MTK/USDC) by pairing my token (MTK) with my stablecoin USDC.
I mint MTK token total supply of 100 million,and 15 million(15%) are supplied to the liquidity pool, and the price is 0.2 USDC to form the initial price.

I expected 15 million MTK and 3 million USDC to be supplied to the MTK/USDC liquidity pool.
Because the initial price is 1 USDC = 5 MTK / 1 MTK = 0.2 USDC.

In this situation, I don't know how to set Price Range (Min/Max) of Uniswap V3 in the most ideal way.

Can anyone give me some good idea?
I would really appreciate it if you could give me an ICO case or link that I can refer to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article discusses when making a price range decision, you should consider the degree to which you think prices will move over the course of your position's lifetime. You should also consider your willingness to actively manage the position as the market evolves, and the economics of transactions required to actively manage a position:

https://support.uniswap.org/hc/en-us/articles/7423194619661-How-to-provide-liquidity-on-Uniswap-V3

Some other resources:

[Creating new uniswap v3 pool - ideal Min/Max price](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/106260/creating-new-uniswap-v3-pool-ideal-min-max-price)

https://blog.tylerbuchea.com/liqudity-pools/